# Float UITableView Image?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am trying to progamatically change the size of my imageView image.
I am trying the cell.imageView.frame method and it's not working.
The deminitons and X-values I set aren't taking play.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([indexPath row] % 2) {
    cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0f/255.0f green:240.0f/255.0f blue:240.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f , 100.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
}
```

Any Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subviews provided by `UITableViewCell` are laid out by the cell itself, so your changes are being overridden the next time the cell lays itself out. You could try subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding `layoutSubviews`, or you could ignore the UITableViewCell-provided subviews and add your own subviews to the `contentView`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am somewhat of a nube in this. How exactally do you subclass a UITableViewCell?

Comment: Much in the same way you create a subclass of any other class: create a class starting with `@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell`.

Comment: Sorry about the language - but you say I should create a cell and manually lay it out in interface builder?

Comment: You can do that, or you can lay it out programmatically without using IB at all.